# AndEngine could not Identify Imported Packages

Tags: android, eclipse, andengine

I am working with andengine and I am stuck at a point, I have a project running to other system, I have new installation.

I am unable to figure out, I have imported project , in settings i have selected AndEngine as external Libraries, but still, No Auto resolve suggestion by compiler/IDE to add the reference,

Below I am attaching screen shot[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click your project

Project Properties

Java Compiler

Compiler Compliance -> 1.6 (Source: Nicolas Gramlich, the guy who made AndEngine)

Create gen and res folder if missing (if there is already, and it still say missing, then delete and recreate it).

Right-click the project -> Properties -> Android, choose Android 4.0 if there is no target selected. Delete all library reference and add its manually again.

And always clean and build your project when you add images or change things.

Good luck!